# How to hide the window, but show on taskbar?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

We need close window when user minimize the window, but keep it on taskbar, like a normal window behavior.

We do this for fixed a problem like: WPF application wink on Win7

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=474986

Image: http://cid-a93b20e2f136913a.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/Capture.png?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=929601453

Comment: I'm curious - what do you think is the difference (to the user) between a "minimized window" and a "closed window that's still on the taskbar?" I'm also not sure what your links have to do with your question - can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the window, when user close the windows. will this meet your requirements?